# RegExp: Trying to understand it. Making a query

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I was running a few tests and thought of one I can see myself using frequently.

So I have a few files around that I would usually `source` as they are common in a lot of things that I would do. I was trying to template it by removing all things after the '=' in a `Name=Value` pair. This means that instead of:
`Foo=Bar`
I would have:
`Foo=`
after I was done using sed to edit my files.

I've tried creating a RegExp statement to do this only remove the Values after the `=` but I can't seem to create one that will match to a single `=` and not multiple (e.g. match `=` but don't match `=====`)

This is the furthest I got before I decided to post: `s/={1}.*/=/g`

Could anyone shed some insight?
I do not want it removing multiple `=` as this is the commonly used formatting  for comments within my team, they use them to split up data entry sections for easier reading.

Some test values:--

```
NameOfServer=Foo   
`#`==========  
`#` UserData   
`#`==========
```

Ideally I would like it to match the '=Foo' in the first line, but not remove the multiple '=' of the commented lines.

Note: I would be using Sed (v4.2) (also Sed within Vim for 'pattern find and replace' if that is any relevance).

Comment: Why do you need it to not much multiple `==`? Do you have sample data we can test our solutions against?

Comment: If we were to describe your change it words, would it be: "in lines that have something that is *not* an equals sign, followed by an equals sign, remove everything after the equals sign"?

Comment: (I have to note that bash isn't a text editor)

Comment: Please note that Vim regular expressions and `sed` regular expressions are very different. (Vim's are much more powerful.) And please explain why `s/=.*/=/` does not do what you want.

Comment: Sorry all - I have now added a better explanation and two examples that directly affect what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable is a string that consists of a `[a-zA-Z_]` character followed by zero or several `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` characters (in the POSIX/C locale).

We can match these strings that are directly followed by a `=`, and delete the rest of the line:

```
sed 's/\([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*=\).*/\1/' file
```

On your example file, this will produce

```
NameOfServer=
`#`==========
`#` UserData
`#`==========
```

Answer (score 1):

`={1}.*` is the same as `=.*`, and will match an equal sign, followed by any amount of any characters. Regexes are usually "greedy", so they try to find the longest match. Using that pattern against a string of equal signs will match the whole string, since there's no way for the regex engine to know you meant characters *other than* equal signs.

Use `=[^=]*` to match an equal sign followed by any amount of characters other than equal signs. Or `=[^=].*` to match an equal sign, followed by any other character, followed by anything.

Or, to match lines with variable assignments more closely, something like

```
sed -Ee 's/^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+=).*/\1/'
```

would check that the line looks like a variable assignment, and then remove anything after the `=`. That assumes the variable names can only contain English letters, numbers and underscores. You may need to adjust that.